# Returning feature class from Python toolbox

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-toolbox

I am trying to return a feature class (my sample data is a polygon fc) from a Python toolbox and cannot find any information about what I have to set to get it to work. This runs successfully and gives me a record count of 917 but in ArcCatalog in the results window `out: <empty>` (and the icon looks like a table not a polygon feature class).

```
import arcpy



class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label='BasicOutput'
        self.alias='BasicOutput'
        self.description='BasicOutput'
        self.summary=self.description

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools=[BasicOutput]


class BasicOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label='BasicOutput'
        self.description='BasicOutput'
        self.summary=self.description


    def getParameterInfo(self):
        ps=[
            arcpy.Parameter(
                displayName='out',
                name='out',
                datatype='GPFeatureRecordSetLayer',
                parameterType='Derived',
                direction='Output'),
            ]
        return ps


    def updateParameters(self,parameters): return
    def updateMessages(self,parameters): return


    def execute(self,parameters,messages):
        fs=arcpy.FeatureSet()
        fs.load(r'D:\customApps\PaddockGRASP\BasicOutput.gdb/Cadastre')
        arcpy.AddMessage('record count: %s'%arcpy.GetCount_management(fs))
        parameters[0].value=fs
```

I will then be publishing it as a GP service in ArcGis server, but can't even get it working in ArcCatalog! Using ArcGis 10.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Change `parameters[0].value=fs` to `arcpy.SetParameterAsText(0,fs)`

EDIT: after some minor testing, looks like `arcpy.SetParameter` also works.

EDIT2: Oops, just noticed that I also changed the datatype to `DEFeatureClass`.

OK, after many hours of trying various things and trawling through forums about problems that weren't the same as mine or about getting features as input instead of output, I stumbled on the simple solution (yet completely unintuitive to me). Despite the name of the function `SetParameterAsText`, it actually sets the return value to my feature class - returns the path in ArcCatalog which I can copy features from and returns JSON when published as a GPService.